# Populate listview according to distance

Tags: android

I am using gooleplaces API. I have a response in json, but the problem is I want to populate listview according to distance. I make the sorted distance arraylist in ascending order using `collections.sort()`, but how do I sort other lists based on this sorted list to populate my listview correctly?

Comment: Please post code, what is the other list here? without knowing more details it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: the other list are namesList & addresslist in which there is names & address of places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve my problem using `bubble sort`.

```
if (distanceList.size()>1) // check if the number of orders is larger than 1
            {
                for (int i=0; i<distanceList.size()-1; i++) // bubble sort outer loop
                {
                    for (int j=0; j < distanceList.size()-1-i; j++) {

                        if (distanceList.get(j)>(distanceList.get(j+1)) )
                        {
                         int temp = distanceList.get(j);
                           distanceList.set(j,distanceList.get(j+1) );
                           distanceList.set(j+1, temp);

                           String temp1 = nameList.get(j);
                           nameList.set(j,nameList.get(j+1) );
                           nameList.set(j+1, temp1);

                           String temp2 = vicinityList.get(j);
                           vicinityList.set(j,vicinityList.get(j+1) );
                           vicinityList.set(j+1, temp2); 

                           String temp3 = latList.get(j);
                           latList.set(j,latList.get(j+1) );
                           latList.set(j+1, temp3);

                           String temp4 = longList.get(j);
                           longList.set(j,longList.get(j+1) );
                           longList.set(j+1, temp4);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating separate lists, then you need to your define method, and if you are using list of single collection, or data structure, you can define your comparator, then call sort on this, list.